# Socket communication in char device driver

Tags: c, sockets, linux-device-driver

Is it feasible to open socket from kernel module of a char device driver in linux? I am trying to emulate the output / input stream of char devices over network. But as far as I searched opening a socket from char device is not possible? Any other option to access udp / tcp ports from char device drivers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can open socket and communicate with remote hosts in kernel code, a vivid example is the `NFS` module, which uses `sunrpc` for its protocols, and both of them are running in kernel module.

As a start, look at `kernel_connect`[1] to start a connection, and `kernel_sock_shutdown` to shutdown the connection. There are a full list of apis in `socket.c`.

[1]http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/net/socket.c#L3212

[2]http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/net/socket.c#L3298

[3]http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/net/socket.c